# Print text from the terminal on a label?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have some text that is printing into the console in Xcode.

I would like to get that text to print on to a label into the viewcontroller. I have created a label and created an outlet as well with it.

How should I get the text that is getting printed into the console to be printed on my label on the viewcontroller?

Answer (score 1):

You can assign text to your label this way:

```
yourLabel.text = yourText.
```

But `yourText` must be a string.